# Дистрибутивы Linux: как улучшить использование меток?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, описание-метки

Есть много различных дистрибутивов Linux. Зачастую меткой конкретного дистрибутива отмечается вопрос, который касается любого дистрибутива. Например, вот такой:

«[Не хватает прав на выполнение скрипта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/226177/181472)»

А бывает и наоборот, отмечено [linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux), а касается не более чем конкретного дистрибутива:

«[Linux Mint. Энергопотребление.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/59682/181472)»

Я почитал описания меток и даже поправил пару. Но там всё равно нет единого порядка. Не везде есть инструкции по использованию и отличия от прочих похожих меток. Предлагаю привести описания к общему стандартному виду. В качестве примера вы можете посмотреть на описания меток Меты группы статус-*, т.е. [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be), [статус-так-задумано](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be) и прочих. Вот что-то подобное я хотел бы видеть в метках дистрибутивов (и, в перспективе, в любой группе сходных меток).

Давайте обсудим:

- Как вообще должны использоваться эти метки?
- Что обязательно должно быть в описании?
- Стоит ли вручную перебирать старые вопросы и переставлять метки на них? (Я считаю, что да).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1)

> Зачастую меткой конкретного дистрибутива отмечается вопрос, который
>   касается любого дистрибутива.

Я в практике использую Ubuntu и CoreOS. Если я задаю вопрос по ним, то буду использовать конкретные метки: [ubuntu](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu), [coreos](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coreos), как минимум потому что я не уверен, что это касается всего семейства [linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux).

> Как вообще должны использоваться эти метки?

Какова цель меток в принципе? Они нужны для того, чтобы было удобно искать по ним, они сужают область. Поэтому, мне кажется, можно всегда ставить [linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) метку, а если речь о конкретном дистрибутиве, то ещё и его метку.

> Что обязательно должно быть в описании?

Ключевые особенности. Хотя тут всё очень сложно...

> Стоит ли вручную перебирать старые вопросы и переставлять метки на
>   них? (Я считаю, что да).

Если найдётся тот, кто в этой теме хорошо разбирается.

p.s. а почему не перенять опыт en SO?